# Straighten edges not on axis

Tags: modeling, edges

I have some edges that are not on the x, y or z axis. What is a simple way to straighten them? For example, I can scale and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to straighten on the x and y axis.

Any shortcuts other than temporarily rotating the entire object to put the edges on an axis?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the 3D view with transform panel open?

Comment: Probably select adjacent vertices that need to be along X axis (for example) and hit S > X > 0?

Comment: use Smooth_Vertex

Comment: I tried smotth vertex :(  strange results. Here is artifical sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/74y908d5rdg36n2/screen.jpg?dl=0  Normally if the edge was aligned to axis I would do as Mr Zak suggested

Answer (score 17):

This is one way to align verities (or straighten edges ) according to two of them (without moving these two ) :

- select these two points (in this case the ends )
- create an edge between them
- set the manipulator to **Normal**
- set the pivot to **Active Element**
- set selection to **Edge**
- select all where the created edge is the active one
- hit <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and again <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, after that type <kbd>0</kbd> and hit 
  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- delete the edge you created

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to the Chebhou answer, I will post a hint to get this problem resolved.

1. Select two vertices, which are in the ending of the edge you'd like to straighten. Hit <kbd>F</kbd> and create edge.

[image]

2. Subdivide this created edge several times, so it to have the same quantity of vertices as you'd like to straighten (in your case 7).

[image]

3. Select one vertice from those you'd like to straighten,  then one from the created edge and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - > At Last.

[image]

4. Repeat that for every vertice you'd like to straighten.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Enable `LoopTools` Addon (it comes with Blender)
2. Select edges to straighten

[image]

3. Press <kbd>W</kbd>, select LoopTools and Gstretch

[image]

4. Play with Gstretch settings

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to create a surplus edge, only a custom orientation.

**To straighten to a line:**

1. Set pivot to 'Active Element'
2. Select 2 vertices to define the line
3. Create a custom orientation using the small '+' in the orientation pop-up. ( I do this a lot, so I also check 'Use after creation' and 'Overwrite previous' in the tool region. It's worth creating a shortcut for this, or adding it to your Quick Menu)

[image]

4. Select all the vertices you would like to lie on the line, ensuring
   one of your defining vertices is active after selection
5. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> , and then  <kbd>0</kbd>.

**To flatten to a plane:**

1. Set pivot to 'Active Element'
2. Select 3 vertices to define the plane
3. Create your orientation.
4. Select all the vertices you would like to lie in the plane, ensuring
   one of your defining vertices is active after selection
5. Hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

As i had similar issue, i will add an answer too.

As an addition to method with the subdivided edge, it is also a nice idea to use vertex snapping to slide verts on this edge to match original ones.

Also there is an addon, shipped with blender - Loop Tools. It has a nice tool - Flatten.