# How to straighten a jumbled line?

Tags: modeling

How can I straighten the shape line in the picture without losing the objects solid form? I usually use ctrl s and 0 to do it, but, that doesn't work in this case.

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis

Comment: Instead of doing crtl s > 0 try crtl s > z > 0

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it, by using the 3D cursor.
[image]

Comment: Nice way, allows to skip creating edges (note that depending on selection you might need to use *Selection to Cursor (Offset)*).

Comment: Nice answer - this is the way I usually do it. I'll add that if one plans to do a lot of snap operations it might help to assign a shortcut to them. I use the following - Cursor to Selected: [ Selection to Cursor: ] Cursor to Grid: Shift [ Selection to Grid: Shift ] These can be assigned by right-clicking on the menu items.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the most simple and versatile method is to use a LoopTools addon and it's Relax feature. This way you can also straighten / relax / smooth multiple vertices which should be almost impossible with the 3D cursor solution above.
For me this addon is a must-have for modeling anyway so I am sure you won't regret installing it.

[image]

This is some example of another usage of this feature:
[image]

Comment: thks man. that's i maean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can double click <kbd>G</kbd> and slide the vertex all the way to one of the connecting vertices. then slide back where you need the vertex to be and you will have a straight line.