# How to align/straighten adjacent edges? (Solved)

Tags: edit-mode, edges

So I've looked on stack here, and I've also tried [here](https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/useful-keyboard-shortcuts.php), but I could not find what I was looking for. I remember looking at this tutorial once, and someone used a fast key or key combination to straighten adjacent edges. 
Look at my image, [image]
What I basically want to do is use that key combination to somewhat align those edges/vertices to be somewhat along the same height on the x-axis. I remember using that key combination on another shirt I made once. You could keep 'spamming' the combination/key until they were (almost) perfectly aligned. 
Anyone happen to know which combination that is?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello :). This thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28063/

Comment: Hey, I saw that one, but it's not that that I need. Thank you for your answer anyways!

Comment: Hi :). Then perhaps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33525/. Or try to better describe your problem.

Comment: I think I found it, but I just remembered it wrong. It worked with the scaling :)