# How can I straigthen vertices along a direction?

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

I want to get the bottom half vertices to follow the direction of the top half vertices.
I tried with scaling along an axis to first straighten them, then rotate them, but it didn't work properly.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis

Comment: I don't know if there's a tool to do that but you could quickly cut with the knife tool (K to activate, Z to cut through) then dissolve the bad edge