# How to move multiple not in plane vertices to a surface or an edge?

Tags: modeling

I am using Blender since few time and I would need to ask you this: is there a way to move (grab) multiple vertices, that are not on the same plane, to a common face (edge)?

My problem is like to project, along a specified vector or direction, a set of vertices without copying them, but, before, moving them.

I have faced this problem when trying to fix some thin face or not planar face in my geometry: in these cases it would be great to create a "brand new" planar face, that lays on the correct plane, and then make all the bad face vertices move on it along a specific vector (to do that I usually create a custom reference system and use one of its axis).

Thank you,
Federico

Comment: That is the question? Custom transform orientation doesn't help?

Comment: @Crantisz Thanks but custom transform orientation, for my knowledge, gives me the possibility to move, copy, rotate, scale, etc...along specific axis other than the default ones. My problem is how to move/project a whole set of vertices on a specific face at once. I can do that one vertex per time, but, when dealing with a lot of vertices as in my case, it is not an efficient solution.

Comment: .. does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/111210/35559

Comment: @Robin Betts Thank you. It's a while I don't come here and I don't use Blender, I have seen your tips right now. That thread is about straightening multiple edges before multiple faces, anyway I will give it a try "adding 1 dimension" to suggestions sent in that thread

Answer (score 0):

### At first, we take a case, when you already have custom transform orientation.

So, I have this setup, with custom orientation:

[image]

1. Set 3D cursor on the plane, that is should be a zero-level for vertexes. Depends on left\right click select mode in your setup, you can press Left Mouse Button, or use a 3D cursor tool.
2. Set transform orientation to 3D-cursor (use <kbd>.</kbd> key):

[image]

3. When press S, Z, 0 to scale vertexes by 0 in z axis.

[image]

### But wait, where is a simpler way

I don't use a transform orientation in this way.

1. At first, I rotate a view in a face direction using Shift+Num 7:

[image]

2. When in the snapping I select Snap to **Faces**, **Project to self** and **Project individual elements**:

[image]

3. When I press G, hold Ctrl and press Left mouse button without moving. As a result, selected vertexes has been projected on face. This method works with curved shapes in background also.

Comment: Thank you. It's a while I don't come here and I don't use Blender. Your way looks really promising, even because it is related to faces before edges, like the tips in the thread Robin Betts has suggested commenting my question. I will give it a try asap. Cheers