# align vertices in a custom direction

Tags: vertices, transform-orientation

how can I align these vertices:

[image: 1]

in a custom direction(not Z Y or X), in order to have them all on a straight line?

Comment: Hello, Dario, welcome. I think it's fair to call this a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28063/35559 . If nonre of the answers there work for you, by all means edit to re-open,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in blender add-ons enable "looptools" and then use gstretch:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Chris, I was just thinking it was fair to call this a duplicate of  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis , and your answer popped up... what  do you think?

Comment: @RobinBetts: you are totally right

Comment: Sorry about your UV and wasted work :(  ... I think this one has to go.

Comment: @RobinBetts: i am used to it....;) Duarte closed in my starting time here nearly everything from me....and quicker, than i could look. But no one asked so friendly and polite like you do! ;) Duarte should learn from you!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment... but on the other hand, Duarte gets a lot of stuff done. We need our Duarte (s)  :)

Comment: i believe that. But i think some people left this site because of him - and i was just an inch away to do that too. He changed his rude writings a bit - luckily.